# Cant instal mysql on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: mysql, 21.04

I am working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.04 or a Dell R610 server.

I recently installed mariadb and a number of Wordpress sites.  I had to remove, purge and autoremove the mariadb because of the error I will present here.  At this point I am starting fresh install of mysql-server.

I did the following steps to install mysql-server

{lsb-release -a}

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

{sudo apt update}
{sudo apt install mysql-server}

Then I checked the install.
{sudo systemctl status mysql}

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 mysql-systemd-start[2426]: MySQL has been frozen to prevent damage to your system. Please see >
Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 13 23:30:57 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I attempted to start MySQL to get the journal -xe output.

{sudo systemctl start mysql}

The journal -xe output is:

```
Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Sep 14 08:23:43 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 16459 and the job result is done.
Sep 14 08:23:43 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 14 08:23:43 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 14 08:23:43 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
```

There are two statements I do not understand and a search on the internet has not resulted in much information.

```
Sep 14 08:23:43 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 14 08:23:43 xxx-R610 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is a brand new build.  So it should not be an issue....unless this is a dev issue and ubuntu 21.04 does not work with MySQL or MariaDB yet.

Any help would be great.   My next attempt will require downgrading ubuntu to 20.04.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/845471/service-start-request-repeated-too-quickly-refusing-to-start-limit for an explanation of the problem that seems clearly shown in your output (`Start request repeated too quickly`), and for the solution.

Comment: 20.04 is an LTS so that is not a downgrade it a different version.

Comment: Thanks @user535733,  for pointing out the thread that explained the problem.  I was able to remove the Start request repeated too quickly error by increasing the DefaultStartLimitBurst=50   .   The error "mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'." remains.